# downloading picture using cocos2d-x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

Im unable to download a picture using the native cocos2d-x functions.
Im using HttpRequest to attempt to download picture on Android.
When i use the URL, InputStream and OutputStream in Java to download the picture.
The picture is valid, when i tried using the native cocos2d-x function. The picture will have a problem. 
The Cocos2d-x version in question is the latest 3.0 as of writing.

Comment: can you explain a bit more? Where are you downloading pictures from? Format of the URL? have you tried cURL?

Comment: I tried to download a Facebook profile picture using the URL. This is the example url: https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/t1.0-1/c23.7.85.85/s50x50/47592_463162731539_7912001_s.jpg

HttpRequest is a wrapper by the game engine, internally it is using cURL. Im not intending to use cURL directly, but if there is no choice, i will try to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cocos2d-x you write this Code

```
void HelloWorld::loadImage()
{
    log("onHttpRequestCompleted In the request");
    HttpRequest* request = new (std::nothrow) HttpRequest();
    request->setUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/100000706355105/picture?width=120&height=120");
    request->setRequestType(cocos2d::network::HttpRequest::Type::GET);
    request->setResponseCallback(CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onRequestImgCompleted, this));
    request->setTag("Post test2");
    HttpClient::getInstance()->send(request);
    request->release();
}
```

On RequestCompleted

```
void HelloWorld::onRequestImgCompleted(HttpClient *sender, HttpResponse *response)
{

    log("In HelloWorld");
    log("AppDelegate::onHttpRequestCompleted - onHttpRequestCompleted BEGIN");
    if (!response)
    {
        log("onHttpRequestCompleted - No Response");
        return;
    }

    log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Response code: %lu", response->getResponseCode());

    if (!response->isSucceed())
    {
        log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Response failed");
        log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Error buffer: %s", response->getErrorBuffer());
        return;
    }
    log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Response code: %s", response->getResponseDataString());

    std::vector<char> *buffer = response->getResponseData();
    const char* file_char = buffer->data();
    log("onHttpRequestCompleted - Response code: %s", file_char);
    Image * image = new  Image ();
    image-> initWithImageData ( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&(buffer->front())), buffer->size());
    Texture2D * texture = new  Texture2D ();
    texture-> initWithImage (image);
    Sprite * sprite = Sprite :: createWithTexture (texture);
    sprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height / 2));
    addChild(sprite);

    log("onHttpRequestCompleted height %f", sprite->getContentSize().height);

}
```